# Не отображаются иконки кнопок ApplicationBar

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Не отображаются иконки кнопок ApplicationBar, код создания:

```
// Конструктор
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Локализация ApplicationBar
        BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    // ApplicationBar
    private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    {
        // Установка нового экземпляра ApplicationBar.
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        // Кнопка "Add"
        ApplicationBarIconButton Add = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/Add.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Add.Text = AppResources.AppBarAdd;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(Add);

        // Кнопка "Edit"
        ApplicationBarIconButton Edit = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/Edit.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Edit.Text = AppResources.AppBarEdit;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(Edit);

        // Кнопка "Delete"
        ApplicationBarIconButton Delete = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/Delete.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Delete.Text = AppResources.AppBarDelete;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(Delete);

        // Кнопка "Connect"
        ApplicationBarIconButton Connect = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/Connect.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Connect.Text = AppResources.AppBarConnect;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(Connect);

    }
```

Иконки в папке /Assets/AppBar/ есть, иконки стандартные, вытащены из самой SDK, размер 76x76, для Dark темы.

Что делать хз, проблема как на эмуляторе так и на телефоне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ:

> You need to add the icons to the
> project as well. In Visual Studio
> select folder Assets. Right click on
> it, select Add Existing Items... In
> the dialog box navigate to you folder
> on disk and select the files you want
> to add (Add.png, Edit.png and
> Delete.png in your case).
>
> Try following this
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431806(v=vs.105).aspx
> to ensure your icons are accessible by
> the project. You will also have issues
> with the size as well so once you get
> it displaying you'll most likely need
> to tweak those details to get the look
> you want.